# Before Insert MySQL trigger replace new.id

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following scenario: I have a product_category table that manage relationships between products and categories with these columns:
id, product_id, category_id

I have another table (cat_eq) that groups some categories with another category with these columns:

```
id, mykey, source_cat_id, destiny_cat_id
```

`source_cat_id` column is a `VARCHAR` that store comma separated id's. For example: 12,25

I need to write a trigger that before inserting in `product_category` table checks if the `new.category_id` is in the set that results when making a `SELECT` given some *mykey* , for example:

```
if(new.category_id in 
    (select source_cat_id from cat_eq where clave = 'man') ) 
then 
  set new.category_id:=(select destiny_cat_id from cat_eq where clave = 'man');
```

When cat_eq has more than one value, let's say (12,15) the trigger works only if the id_category is in the first place of cat_eq table row.

What I want to get is the equivalent of this, which works ok in the trigger:

```
if(new.category_id in (12,25) ) 
then 
    set new.category_id:=(select destiny_cat_id from cat_eq where clave = 'man');
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you need to do is fix your data model. In no way should you ever store a comma delimited list (except in a staging table  to process incoming records), This should be a related table.

Comment: @HLGEM While that's great in theory, it's often not practical. A CMS, for example, already locks the developer into a particular schema, even if it isn't optimal.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()` is a good function for a bad design.

Comment: Why would you buy a CMS from a company so incompetent at database design that they make this error?  I mean really this is the first normal form.The rest of the software is likely poorly thought out and designed as well and is almost 100% guaranteed to have data integrity issues. I would never trust a piece of software to do anything right that makes a database 101 day 1 error. Sorry for the rant, but the sheer incompetence of most off the shelf software is appalling.

Comment: @HLGEM I've never said it's a good db design, but sometimes certain situations require not optimal solutions. There's much background behind this database and lots of stuff going on and there is a reason to make it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think REGEXP is the easy solution here:

```
IF EXISTS
  select 1 from cat_eq where clave = 'man' AND 
     source_cat_id REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)', new.category_id, '(,|$)')
```

Basically, you're looking for something that either starts with the category_id and then is followed by a comma, starts with a comma is followed by the category_id then another comma, or starts with a comma, is followed by the category_id then matches the end.

A second approach might just be a LIKE clause:

```
select 1 from cat_eq where clave = 'man' 
     AND CONCAT(',',source_cat_id,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',category_id,',%')
```